# Ruby: refactor simple string method for aligning DSV text

Tags: ruby, strings

GOAL:

- Accept DSV strings where the delimiter may consist of more than one character
- Accept DSV strings where there are no embedded delimiters
- Output text with no modification to the source string other than aligning custom delimiter with optional padding

QUESTION:

- Anyone have a re-factor or stylistic enhancement or two?

CODE:

```
module DreftymacAddon
  module String
    ### <region-fdef ddef="dsvpretty ;; lineup delims pretty print dsv text with lined up delimiters ">
    def dsvpretty(delim=';;',padd='')
      sout    =   ""
      asizes  =   []
      alines  =   self.to_s.split(/[\x0a\x0d]/)
      alines.each{|currline|
        currline.split(delim).each_with_index{|currfld,icc|
          asizes[icc] = [asizes[icc].to_i,currfld.length].max()
        }
      }
      alines.each{|currline|
        next if currline.strip == ''
        atemp   = []
        currline.split(delim).each_with_index{|currfld,icc|
          atemp << sprintf("%-#{asizes[icc]}s", currfld)
        }
        sout += atemp.join([padd , delim , padd].join(''))
        sout += "\n"
      }
      sout
    end
    alias :dsv_pretty :dsvpretty
    ### </region-fdef>
  end
end

class String
  include DreftymacAddon::String
end


### String.new().dsvpretty ;; example usage
##{
if(1000!=0);
  vout   = %Q[
    LNAME|FNAME|AMOUNT|AGE|NATION|PLATFORM
    Rodriguez|Johan|30.00|58|uk|windows_xp
    Raynor|Coty|40.00|14|uk|redhat
    Bruen|Jackie|30.00|17|uk|ubuntu
    Breitenberg|Waldo|20.00|14|canada|mac_osx
    Collier|Lucy|30.00|22|canada|windows_vista
    Blick|Emmett|30.00|59|canada|knoppix
    Schroeder|Myrtis|10.00|29|uk|knoppix
    Rodriguez|Ashtyn|20.00|22|uk|mac_osx
    Leuschke|Sigmund|40.00|21|france|redhat
    Fahey|Cassidy|40.00|29|canada|knoppix    
  ]

  puts vout.dsvpretty('|','')
=begin
    LNAME      |FNAME  |AMOUNT|AGE|NATION|PLATFORM     
    Rodriguez  |Johan  |30.00 |58 |uk    |windows_xp   
    Raynor     |Coty   |40.00 |14 |uk    |redhat       
    Bruen      |Jackie |30.00 |17 |uk    |ubuntu       
    Breitenberg|Waldo  |20.00 |14 |canada|mac_osx      
    Collier    |Lucy   |30.00 |22 |canada|windows_vista
    Blick      |Emmett |30.00 |59 |canada|knoppix      
    Schroeder  |Myrtis |10.00 |29 |uk    |knoppix      
    Rodriguez  |Ashtyn |20.00 |22 |uk    |mac_osx      
    Leuschke   |Sigmund|40.00 |21 |france|redhat       
    Fahey      |Cassidy|40.00 |29 |canada|knoppix
=end  

  puts vout.dsvpretty('|',' ')
=begin
    LNAME       | FNAME   | AMOUNT | AGE | NATION | PLATFORM     
    Rodriguez   | Johan   | 30.00  | 58  | uk     | windows_xp   
    Raynor      | Coty    | 40.00  | 14  | uk     | redhat       
    Bruen       | Jackie  | 30.00  | 17  | uk     | ubuntu       
    Breitenberg | Waldo   | 20.00  | 14  | canada | mac_osx      
    Collier     | Lucy    | 30.00  | 22  | canada | windows_vista
    Blick       | Emmett  | 30.00  | 59  | canada | knoppix      
    Schroeder   | Myrtis  | 10.00  | 29  | uk     | knoppix      
    Rodriguez   | Ashtyn  | 20.00  | 22  | uk     | mac_osx      
    Leuschke    | Sigmund | 40.00  | 21  | france | redhat       
    Fahey       | Cassidy | 40.00  | 29  | canada | knoppix
=end    

end
##}
```

Comment: As usual I'd recommend re-writing it in functional style, code with side-effects is harder to understand. Are you insterested in how it'd look?

Comment: @tokland Yes, definitely. If and when you have a moment, if you could provide a quick sketch or demonstration link(s), that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes:

- `include DreftymacAddon::String`. Monkeypatching common classes is always controversial, but in this case I wouldn't do it, it's not a general enough abstraction.
- As always, I'd recommend using [functional style with Ruby](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming) (if you check my other answers in this site, it's all I do ;-)) unless you have a very good reason not to. No `sout = ""`, `asize = []`, `each`, `array[key] = value`, `+=` and other statements, use expressions.
- `dsvpretty(delim=';;',padd='')`. This kind of signature is problematic, if you want to set `padd` you are forced to set also `delim` when you wanted to keep the default value. Use an `options` hash instead. Note that finally [Ruby 2.0 provides keyword arguments](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/).
- `each_with_index{|currfld,icc|`. Let the block breathe, and don't forget spaces after commas: `each_with_index { |currfld, icc|`. More on [idiomatic Ruby](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyIdioms).

I'd write:

```
module DreftymacAddon
  def self.dsv_pretty(string, options = {})
    options = {:delim => ";", :padding => ""}.merge(options)
    rows = string.strip.split(/\n/).map { |line| line.strip.split(options[:delim]) }
    columns_max_width = rows.map { |row| row.map(&:size) }.transpose.map(&:max)
    columns_separator = options[:padding] + options[:delim] + options[:padding]

    rows.map do |row|
      row.zip(columns_max_width).map do |cell, column_max_width|
        cell.ljust(column_max_width)
      end.join(columns_separator)
    end.join("\n")
  end
end

puts DreftymacAddon::dsv_pretty(vout, :delim => '|', :padding => " ")
```

Comment: Very nice, well-explained and well-substantiated refactoring, thanks for the links. Will have to upvote some of your other posts since it is not possible to multiple-upvote this one ;-)

Comment: @dreftymac: glad to help, thanks for the other upvotes :-)